# Parallelizing a task with Dask that for each row in a Dataframe returns None

Tags: dataframe, dask

I want to speed up a task on a Dataframe that, for each row, saves an image to a local folder. So, it doesn't return anything. I tried to run that function using Dask, but Dask seems to require that the function return something; I cannot make .apply work...

Is there any other way to make this work?

### Update: Minimally reproducible example

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

doc = pd.DataFrame({'file_name': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice','Allan'], 
               'text': ['text1','text2', 'text3','text4']})

def func(row):
    with open(row['file_name']+'.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(row['text'])

ddf = dd.from_pandas(doc, npartitions=2)
k = ddf.apply(func,axis=1,meta=(None,'object'))
k.compute()
```

The only reason meta is (None,'object') is because that's what Dask itself suggested when I ran similar code without a meta argument.

This doesn't produce any errors, and it correctly runs.. I am now not able to reproduce my own mistake since I corrected my original mistake yesterday with Michael Delgados answer..

Comment: Can you provide your code, ideally as an [mre]?

Comment: Oh I don’t recommend writing to the same file this way. If you do do this, definitely use lock objects to make sure only one workers ids writing to the file at a time

Comment: @MichaelDelgado Oh.. Well, yeah, that was just my pathetic attempt at a minimal reproducible example... I am actually creating images.. I have edited it to look more like my actual code..

Comment: The piece that’s missing is the dataset. Can you create the data from code? A truly reproducible example should be able to be run straight through in a new interpreter session. See the guide to creating a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to make use of the function [`dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions.html). This calls the passed function on each *partition*, each of which is itself a `pandas.DataFrame`. Within that, you can apply a function if you'd like.

For example, the following defines a dataframe with the columns `i` and `n`, then maps a function across each row which writes a file based on the row's values:

```py
import os
import tempfile

def do_something_with_side_effects(row, dirname):
    fp = os.path.join(dirname, f"{row.i}_{row.n}.txt")
    with open(fp, 'w+') as f:
        f.write("file contents!")

def do_something_in_partitions(df, dirname):
    df.apply(do_something_with_side_effects, axis=1, dirname=dirname)

df = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(
    pd.DataFrame({'i': ['A'] * 10 + ['B'] * 5, 'n': np.arange(15)}),
    chunksize=5,
)
```

The trick with getting `dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions` right is providing the `meta` argument, which is needed for dask to understand how to schedule the operation. If you're not returning anything, you can simply provide an empty dictionary:

```py
In [18]: tempdir = str(tempfile.TemporaryDirectory())
    ...: os.makedirs(tempdir, exist_ok=True)
    ...: f = df.map_partitions(do_something_in_partitions, meta={}, dirname=tempdir)
    ...: f.compute()
    ...: os.listdir(tempdir)
Out[18]:
['A_7.txt',
 'A_6.txt',
 'A_4.txt',
 'A_5.txt',
 'A_1.txt',
 'A_0.txt',
 'A_2.txt',
 'A_3.txt',
 'B_12.txt',
 'B_13.txt',
 'B_11.txt',
 'B_10.txt',
 'A_8.txt',
 'B_14.txt',
 'A_9.txt']
```

Comment: That's interesting. I couldn't make map_partitions work, but the empty dictionary trick worked with apply. Thank you!